# Get unique symmetric pairs from two columns with SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have been looking at similar questions on Stack but any of them seems to be helpful to me. I have the following table called "Likes":

```
 ID1    ID2
1689    1709
1709    1689
1782    1709
1911    1247
1247    1468
1641    1468
1316    1304
1501    1934
1934    1501
1025    1101
```

I want to get the unique pairs between the two columns ID1 and ID2. That is:

```
 ID1    ID2
1689    1709
1501    1934
```

Any idea? Thx.

Comment: why only these 2 rows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you want pairs that exist in both versions, i.e. both as (x, y) and (y, x).

Can be done with a `EXISTS` query:

```
select t1.c1, t1.c2
from tablename t1
where t1.c1 < t1.c2
  and exists (select 1 from tablename t2
              where t1.c1 = t2.c2
                and t1.c2 = t2.c1)
```

Or as a `JOIN`:

```
select t1.c1, t1.c2
from tablename t1
join tablename t2
    on  t1.c1 = t2.c2
    and t1.c2 = t2.c1
where t1.c1 < t1.c2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the functions `min` and `max` to get the smallest and greatest of id1,id2 and look for symmetric pair combinations (a,b),(b,a) (count of a pair > 1). Then `left join` this on to the original table to get one such pair.

```
select l.*
from likes l
left join (select min(id1,id2) as minid,max(id1,id2) as maxid 
           from likes
           group by min(id1,id2),max(id1,id2)
           having count(*) > 1) t on t.minid=l.id1 and t.maxid=l.id2
where t.minid is null and t.maxid is null
```

[`Sample Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/be8576/1)

If you only need one pair when a symmetric pair exists, use

```
select min(id1,id2) as minid,max(id1,id2) as maxid 
from likes
group by min(id1,id2),max(id1,id2)
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: I think the OP is looking for the symmetric pairs, not for the non-symmetric pairs. I.e. your subquery only.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner .. `I want to get the unique pairs between the two columns ID1 and ID2` .. from this i understood he wanted one such pair when symmetric pairs exist and all the other pairs as-is.

Comment: Yes, the phrase seems to indicate this and the expected results contradict it. Well, now, with both answers given you can't be wrong ;-)

Comment: That's right. I wanted one such pair when symmetric pairs exist and without duplicates. Sorry, I did not explain myself correctly. I changed the title to be more accurate. The sample demo works perfectly BTW. Many thx