# Get unique symmetric pairs from two columns with Bash Script

Tags: bash, shell, csv

The similar question as below: [Get unique symmetric pairs from two columns with SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44001033/get-unique-symmetric-pairs-from-two-columns-with-sqlite/44001218#44001218)

I am planning to do the data preprocessing initial in python(estimated time too long) -> try to use sql(kept spinning) -> now I am planning to try out the bash. (arounf 80M rows/ 3.3G)

csv file

```
ID1    ID2
1689    1709
1709    1689
1782    1709
1911    1247
1247    1468
1641    1468
1316    1304
1501    1934
1934    1501
1025    1101
```

output

```
 ID1    ID2
1689    1709
1501    1934
```

Any ideas of how to implement in, I've try out like this, but it's not what I want:

```
awk -F"\t" '!seen[$3, $4]++' action_with_gender.csv
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this awk script:

```
awk -F"\t" '{seen[$1, $2]++};seen[$2, $1]++==1' file
```

The first and second field are stored in the array `seen`, and both fields are printed only if the inverted field pair is already present in the array.

The `==1` at the end of the script allows to remove duplicates.

Comment: May be more understandable one -> `awk '{seen[$1, $2]++; if ( seen[$2,$1] == 1 ) print $1}' file`

Comment: As the quick question: If I am curious about the row number of the query. ```awk '{seen[$1, $2]++; if ( seen[$2,$1] == 1 ) print $1}' file | wc -l```

Comment: [There's a variable `NR` that keeps a current count of the number of input records.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/awk-command-unixlinux-examples/) . `awk '{seen[$1, $2]++; if ( seen[$2,$1] == 1 ) print $1,NR }' file`